# Antlr 4 can not compile direct recursive expressions with parameters

Tags: java, parameters, antlr4

ANTLR 4 supports direct left recursion as follows:

```
grammar test2;

options {
    language = Java;
}


start : expr;

expr :
    NUMBER
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr;


NUMBER:
    ('+'|'-')? DIGIT+;

fragment
DIGIT:
    '0'..'9';
```

but if  `expr` has parameters, for example:

```
expr [ int i] :
    NUMBER
    | expr[&i] ('+'|'-') expr[&i]
    ;
```

it will fail during compilation with error messages as below:
`can't find rule grammarSpec or tree structure error:...`.

Currently ANTLR 4 doesn't support such expressions or did I  make some mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Rules which contain direct left recursion may not contain a user-defined argument list. Note that the generated code *will* contain an argument, which is created during the automatic left recursion elimination step.